# Flutter rich content localization

Tags: flutter, dart, internationalization

The package `intl` exists to localize the flutter application but the `Intl.message` only returns `String`

How can I have a rich content localization?

1. `Hello $name!` , and make only `$name` bold, Consider that the order of hello and $name can be different in different languages
2. `I read terms of services and accepted it` , and link only `terms of services` part
3. `in [TEXT_INPUT] days` , the [TEXT_INPUT] has a text after and a text before, but in some languages there is no 2 text, just one text after or before, or `days` is before and `in` is after `[TEXT_INPUT]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [slang](https://pub.dev/packages/slang) package has built-in rich text support.

It will look like this:

```json
{
  "myRichText(rich)": "Welcome {name}"
}
```

```dart
Widget a = Text.rich(t.myRichText(
  // Show name in blue color
  name: TextSpan(text: 'Tom', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue)),
));
```

Comment: Wow slang is advanced, there are obfuscation features that a little thing but important for my project. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 7):

Have a look at the [styled_text](https://pub.dev/packages/styled_text) package. You get to specify the text (content) separately from the formatting, witch allows you to use standard i18n approaches.

Text format is specified as *tags* wich you can define globally (e.g. in a resource class) and then use everywhere. Sounds like a good solution to me.

Example (from the Readme):

```
StyledText(
  text: 'Test: <bold>bold</bold> text.',
  tags: {
    'bold': const StyledTextTag(style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
  },
)
```

will display like:

Test: **bold** text.

If you use the i18n package and a resource class instance `R` for the tags, this might look like:

```
StyledText(
  text: S.testBoldText,
  tags: R.styledTextTags,
);
```

Just keep in mind that the tags need to be preserved in translation.

Comment: What a great tool! Thanks for sharing :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how you can inject variables into your translation.

```
"hello_name": "Hello {name}",
"@hello_name": {
        "placeholders": {
            "name": {
                "type": "String"
            }
        }
    },
```

This will generate a function `hello_name` for you to pass `name`

There is no styling support but if you need it then just don't use `placeholders` like in the above example and have your text be separate and style it using `RichText` where you specify what parts of your text need to have what styling. You don't need to worry about directionality as it will be handled for you depending on your local.

Comment: I know it intl has inject variables, the problem is there is no advanced options for variable, see my 3rd example, we cannot have a text field variable

Comment: There are no advanced options as you know. So as you probably know you can use `RichText` to work around this.

Comment: Ok thanks, I just wanted to be sure

Comment: I use this mark_down package to add some simple styles to localised strings. https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_markdown